# GET http://localhost:8001/socket.io/1/?t=1441787711937 404 (Not Found)

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, sockets, socket.io

socket.io is not working....am getting the error message http://localhost:8001/socket.io/1/?t=1441787711937 404 (Not Found) from the console.

Here is the server code (serverPackage.js). Using node-static

```
var static = require('node-static');
var http = require('http');
var file = new(static.Server)();

var app = http.createServer(function(req, res) {
    file.serve(req, res);
}).listen(8001);

var io = require('socket.io').listen(app);

io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {

    socket.on('message', function(message) {
        log('S --> got message: ', message);

        socket.broadcast.to(message.channel).emit('message', message);
    });

    socket.on('create or join', function(room) {
        var numClients = io.sockets.clients(room).length;
        log('S --> Room ' + room + ' has ' + numClients + ' client(s)');
        log('S --> Request to create or join room', room);

        if (numClients == 0) {
            socket.join(room);
            socket.emit('created', room);
        } else if (numClients == 1) {

            io.sockets.in(room).emit('join', room);
            socket.join(room);
            socket.emit('joined', room);
        } else {
            socket.emit('full', room);
        }
    });

    function log() {
        var array = [">>> "];
        for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
            array.push(arguments[i]);
        }
        socket.emit('log', array);
    }
});
```

and this is how the socket.io is link to the browser: (index.html)

```
<script src='http://localhost:8001/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/socket.io-client/dist/socket.io.js'></script>
```

the package.json is

```
{
  "name": "video_call",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "A simple video call app",
  "main": "serverPackage",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "AOS",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies":{
  "express":"3.x",
  "socket.io":"0.9.x"
  }

}
```

I have the index.html, the serverPackage.js, the package.json and the (node_modules folder) in the same folder directory.

I do not know what is wrong and why it cant find it. can anyone please help me out.

Comment: Sorry, but is your intention really to have a server that statically *serves your server side source code*?

Comment: I thought with that is might work base on the tutorial am reading..any help on how I can make it work?

Comment: @JHH can I make it work without that? any help?